# Timing sequence in MapReduce

Tags: efficiency, map-reduce, performance, experiments

I'm running a test on MapReduce algorithm in different environments, like Hadoop and MongoDB, and using different types of data. What are the different methods or techniques to find out the execution time of a query.

If I'm inserting a huge amount of data, consider it to be 2-3GB, what are the methods to find out the time for the process to be completed.

Answer (score 0):

One option is the [`time`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) command on the command line.